# Answers extraction from an unstructured text

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I want to extract some answers for a group of given questions from an unstructured text. I searched a library for this proposal but I haven't found it.

p.s. I have used NLP tools/libraries, such as NLTK, OpenNLP, etc...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask for a Question Answering (QA) toolkit. Its rarely to find an open source code or a ready to use system. You can look for scientific articles that describe a QA system and try to replicate it from using the toolkits that you mentioned above. Normally these systems use NER taggger, POS, coreference resolution, etc..